# Calling code behind with event handler not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a web page that consists of two dropdown boxes and a gridview. I have created a web service that collects the data for the drop down boxes and I have used a ajax call to populate them. The issue I am having is when I try to add a OnSelectedIndexChanged event handler, it does not seem to be working correctly. I have looked around and I have tried a few things. I have set EnableEventValidation to false (I presume this fixed an issue related to my ddl being populated dynamically in js). I have also enabled AutoPostBack on my ddl.

When I change the ddl index, the page seems to be posting back but my dll index reverses back to the previous selected index.

```
<div class="row control-group">
     <div class="form-group col-xs-12" id="mailbox">
           <label>Which bills would you like to view?</label>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUser" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUser_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
           <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `var a = 1`; is just so that I can put a breakpoint there.

```
protected void ddlUser_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var a = 1;
}
```

Below is the ajax request and the generating of the grid

```
function getUsers() {

  var department = $('select#MainContent_ddlDepartment option:selected').val();

  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "WEBSERVICEURL" + department + "",
      contentType: "json",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
          var ddlUsers = $("#MainContent_ddlUser");
          ddlUsers.empty();
          $.each(data, function () {
              ddlUsers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['SamAccountName']).html(this['DisplayName']));
          });
      },
      error: function (xhr) {
      }
  })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your asp.net controls inside a asp:form with runat=server?

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle yes

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.There is a security feature built into ASP.NET called Event Validation which prevents you from posting data which was not there when the page was created by the server.

You (or a hacker) is changing the drop down options using javascript and then tries to submit the changes to the server through `SelectedIndexChanged` - can you see why this is not allowed?

As a workaround you can implement a`change()` event on the drop down using jQuery and make a server side call using $.ajax:

```
$("#ddlUser").change(function () {
    alert("write $.ajax call to call the server here...");
});
```

Comment: I presume that I am locked down to using only client side call now then? other than using more ajax as you mentioned. Does this effect other elements on the page or just these ddls? Thanks

Comment: It affects all server side controls in ASP.NET.You're definitely not "locked down" to using the client code.You can always created a OnSelectedIndexChanged on ddlDepartment and bind ddlUser from server side.If you do it that way then you can call OnSelectedIndexChanged for ddlUser and the filtered dropdowns are completely done server side

Comment: Unfortunately the department ddl is also populated client side. The reason for these drop downs is to change the data in a gridview depending on the selection user in the ddl. Correct me if I am wrong but WebMethods need to be static and you can't reference a control from a static method? Many Thanks

Comment: Well the ddl is populated client side only because you programmed it that way.The bottom line is it doesn't have to be that way.You can do all the data binding in the code behind then you won't have the problem of not being able to invoke OnSelectedIndexChanged and if you are going to do the data binding on the client side then you need to repond to drop down change events from javascript, it's quite simple.